# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 137 issue:Leaflet mapview

Tags: pandoc

Recently I was compiling a R Markdown html. Everithing was ok until I inserted a chunk with a leaflet or MapView object.
Since then I am unable to finish compiling to html.

my machie is

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status         Patched
major          4
minor          2.2
year           2022
month          11
day            10
svn rev        83330
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting

Packages
pandoc     v0.1.0
knir       v1.42
rmarkdown  v2.21

The complete error is this:
`Killed Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 137 In addition: Warning messages: 1: In in_dir(input_dir(), expr) : You changed the working directory to /home/alfredo/Dropbox/1.Epidat/Consultoria ASPE/Informes dinámicos/cvmppc (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to /home/alfredo. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit 2: 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode' Valid attributes include: '_deprecated', 'alignmentgroup', 'base', 'basesrc', 'cliponaxis', 'constraintext', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextanchor', 'insidetextfont', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'offset', 'offsetgroup', 'offsetsrc', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'outsidetextfont', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'text', 'textangle', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'width', 'widthsrc', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignm [... truncated]  3: 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode' Valid attributes include: '_deprecated', 'alignmentgroup', 'base', 'basesrc', 'cliponaxis', 'constraintext', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextanchor', 'insidetextfont', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'offset', 'offsetgroup', 'offsetsrc', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'outsidetextfont', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'text', 'textangle', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'width', 'widthsrc', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignm [... truncated]  4: 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode' Valid attributes include: '_deprecated', 'alignmentgroup', 'base', 'basesrc', 'cliponaxis', 'constraintext', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextanchor', 'insidetextfont', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'offset', 'offsetgroup', 'offsetsrc', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'outsidetextfont', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'text', 'textangle', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'width', 'widthsrc', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignm [... truncated]  5: 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode' Valid attributes include: '_deprecated', 'alignmentgroup', 'base', 'basesrc', 'cliponaxis', 'constraintext', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextanchor', 'insidetextfont', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'offset', 'offsetgroup', 'offsetsrc', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'outsidetextfont', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'text', 'textangle', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'width', 'widthsrc', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignm [... truncated]  Execution halted`

I reinstalled the packages and restart computer, RStudio, R. Without success.
I tried using the create_report() function to use the hmtl function instead of pandoc, but didn't work.
there are another options using java, but I can't use it.

Please is there any posibility to change the compiler from pandoc to html when using the
rmarkdown::render() I would aprecciated it very much.